# How do you modify the stage (Stage/Live) of a DataList in Silverstripe 3.2?

Tags: php, web, silverstripe

Does anyone know how to modify the stage of a DataList in Silverstripe 3.2? I want to modify a DataList in my grid field component to change based on the ?_GET['stage'] parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this like so below.

```
class GridFieldChangeStage implements GridField_DataManipulator {
    /*
     * Modifies the DataList stage accordingly
     */
    public function getManipulatedData(GridField $gridField, SS_List $dataList)
    {
        $isShowingLiveData = (isset($_GET['stage']) && $_GET['stage'] == 'Live');
        if ($isShowingLiveData) {
            $dataList = $dataList->alterDataQuery(function($dataQuery) {
                $dataQuery->setQueryParam('Versioned.mode', 'stage');
                $dataQuery->setQueryParam('Versioned.stage', 'Live');
            });
        }
        return $dataList;
    }
}
```